How to compute the total number of words in a text file
I am given a text file (call it text.txt). I need to count the total number of words (counting repetitions as well). My code begins like this:
def words():
    f = sc.textFile("text.txt")
    return f.DO_SOME_MAGIC()

So my question reduces to: What should go to DO_SOME_MAGIC?
PS
For the following text file:
hello world
bye world

I should receive 4 and NOT:
(hello, 1)
(bye, 1)
(world, 2)


If you’re willing to use something other than python, the wc tool does this quite efficiently

@Marc It’s a school assignment. I have no choice.

return f.flatMap(lambda line: line.split()).count()

Try this will work fine
def words():
    f = sc.textFile("text.txt")
    return f.flatMap(lambda line: line.split()).count()

without repetition
def words():
    f = sc.textFile("text.txt")
    return f.flatMap(lambda line: line.split()).distinct().count()


Try this:
def words():
    f = sc.textFile("text.txt")
    return f.flatMap(lambda line: line.split()).count()

Your DO_SOME_MAGIC() is flatMap with count().
